# POST Request runs without error but does not do what it should

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So I have been having some trouble with requests and I don't know why this is happening. I realized this before, but I thought it was something on my part (it still probably is but I don't know what it is, hence the question) I was working on a script for Instagram. I got it to create the Instagram account just fine. However I want it to follow a person I want. This is the code I used:

```
    pat = '/web/friendships/' + e + '/follow/'
headers = {
    'authority': 'www.instagram.com',
    'method': 'POST',
    'path': pat,
    'scheme': 'https',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.7,zh;q=0.6',
    'content-length': '0',
    'origin': 'https://www.instagram.com',
    'referer': link,
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36',
    'x-csrftoken': 'eARRsWAqOvY73Xi9Fe3WLrWK9Rdxjy6o',
    'x-instagram-ajax': 'a6abd1200036',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}


link = 'https://www.instagram.com/web/friendships/' + e + '/follow/'
w = s.post(link, headers = headers,proxies = proxies)

print(Fore.YELLOW + time.strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]") + Fore.GREEN + 'Followed ' + e)
```

So this request runs without any errors. I have set `s = requests.Session()` at the beginning of the script already. AFAIK this replicates the POST request exactly like when you follow on Instagram. Then why is this not working??? I got no errors when the script ran.

Another example of this problem is in a Slickdeals script I was working on. I got the account logging in to work but when I go to a listing and try to Vote up using requests the same thing happens (no errors in the script however it doesn't vote up). The code I used is this:

```
cool = {
'authority': 'slickdeals.net',
'method': 'POST',
'path': '/forums/sdthreadrate_ajax.php',
'scheme': 'https',
'accept': '*/*',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language': 'en,en-US;q=0.9',
'origin': 'https://slickdeals.net',
'referer': link,
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36',
'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
 }
vote_up_payload = {
   'ajax': '1',
   'do': 'sdthreadratevote',
   'postid': postid,
   'vote': '1',
   'votetypeid': '1',
   'controltype': 'modern',
   'securitytoken': sec_token,
   'where_from': '/forums/sdthreadrate_ajax.php',
}
voteu = s.post('https://slickdeals.net/forums/sdthreadrate_ajax.php', 
headers = cool, data = vote_up_payload)
print('done')
```

So what is the problem? Why does the script work but not do what it should?

[EDIT]: Ok the instagram issue makes sense. Any reason as to why the slickdeals doesn't work?

Comment: Because Instagram don't want you to interact programatically with their website. Use their API, that's what it's for.

Comment: What about slickdeals?